# Ускорить алгоритм поиска количества чисел, не кратных 7

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Написал такой алгоритм, он выдает правильные результаты, но очень долго решает. В файле задаются 2 числа - a и b (a < b), нужно найти в этом промежутке(a - b) количество чисел не кратных 7, как ускорить этот алгоритм?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int a = 0, b = 0, ans = 0;

    ifstream inp;
    ofstream otp;
    inp.open("input.txt");
    otp.open("output.txt");

    inp >> a >> b;
    for (; a <= b; a++) {
        if (a % 7 != 0) {
            ans++;
        }
    }

    otp << ans;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: *как ускорить этот алгоритм?* Отказаться от тупого перебора, немножко подумать и вывести прямую формулу.

Comment: @Akina формулу для промежутка?

Comment: Можно и для промежутка... но проще `F(a,b) = F(1,b) - F(1,a-1)`.

Comment: @Akina не понимаю, что это за формула? F-?

Comment: @ValeraGrinenko, а количество **кратных 7** быстро (без перебора) найти сможете? Подсказка -- они отличаются друг от друга на 7

Comment: @avp в интервале без цикла не смогу, есть идея найти первое кратное и отнимать от числа 7 каждый раз добавляя к ответу 1, но нужен цикл

Comment: Ну, можно же просто разделить новый интервал (от первого больше чем `a` до `b`) на 7 и получится количество отрезков длиной 7, котрые там укладываются. Просто порисуйте карандашом эти интервалы и отрезки

Comment: @Akina а зачем тут применять динамику ?? разве это не `(b - a) - (b - a)/7` ?

Comment: или что тоже самое `6*(b - a)/7`

Comment: @ampawd Лучше было сперва подумать... В твоём варианте ответ абы зависит от разности и не зависит от границ, что есть заведомый бред. Например, (3..5) и (6..8) - разности равны, а вот ответы нет.

Comment: @Akina ок,поторопился. Но все равно динамика тут ни к чему. ответ это `(b - a + 1) - ( floor(b/7) - floor(a/7) )` это если ни `b` ни `a` не делятся на 7 и `(b  - a) - ... ` если хотя бы один из концов (или оба) делится на 7. Тоесть тупо из количества всех чисел из диапазона вычитаем кол-во кратных 7 и получаем константную временную сложность

Comment: @ampawd Так прямая формула она формула и есть... и никакой динамики в ней нет и быть не может, от слова "вообще". Так что я не понимаю, где в моём предложении можно было найти какую-то "динамику"...

Comment: @ampawd эта формула не работает, больше половины тестов провалено.

Comment: @ValeraGrinenko можно ссылку на эту задачу где можно будет решение сабмитить ?

Comment: @ampawd не могу, ресурс закрытый. Могу условие кинуть.
 https://imgur.com/a/Fzo5Lq7

Comment: @ValeraGrinenko Какие ЕЩЁ нужны идеи? используя указанный мной подход, несложно создать программу, время работы которой будет не больше ошибки измерения этого времени (если, конечно, не считать такты процессора), а расход памяти сведётся к 4 целым переменным. Осталось всё это оформить в виде программного кода  - но это уж как-нибудь самостоятельно...

Comment: @Akina если я правильно понял, то тут F(a,b) = F(1,b) - F(1,a-1) нужно перебирать 2 раза чтобы подсчитать, и что если a или b < 0 ?

Comment: Не надо ничего перебирать... `F(1,x) = x - x DIV 7`.

Comment: Написал такой код https://ideone.com/6TlbmH (Мое решение, достаточно глупое, считаю количество элементов в массиве, затем количество четных 7, и вычитаю из кол-ва элементов кол-во четных - все тесты пройдены)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подразумевая `a <= b`:

1. Выровняем значение `a` *вверх* к ближайшему кратному 7

   ```
   int a7 = (a + 7 - 1) / 7 * 7; // см. ниже о делении
   ```
2. Выровняем значение `b` *вниз* к ближайшему кратному 7

   ```
   int b7 = b / 7 * 7; // см. ниже о делении
   ```
3. Посчитаем количество чисел, кратных 7 в нашем диапазоне

   ```
   int k7 = a7 <= b7 ? (b7 - a7) / 7 + 1 : 0;
   ```
4. Вычтем это значение из общего количества чисел в диапазоне

   ```
   int n7 = (b - a + 1) - k7;
   ```

   Это и есть ответ задачи.

Если значения `a` и `b` могут быть отрицательными, то в шагах 1 и 2 вместо языкового целочисленного деления `/` следует реализовать и использовать Евклидово деление

```
int euclidean_div(int a, int b)
{ // Для `b > 0`
  return a >= 0 ? a / b : (a - b + 1) / b;
}
```